# Membership SettingsPropertyNotFoundException after session was lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, membership

I am using membership and have created a custom profile that contains a property called FirstName. It works well except when the session/cookies are lost (I haven't figured out exactly which since it's pretty hard to reproduce). Then when I access any page of the site I get this exception:

> [SettingsPropertyNotFoundException: The settings property 'FirstName' was not
>   found.]
>      System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String
>   propertyName) +8757578
>      System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName) +118
>      System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.GetInternal(String propertyName) +49
>      System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.get_Item(String propertyName) +129
>      WebFrontend.Security.SecurityHandler.get_FullName() +168
>      WebFrontend.Controls.LoginInfo.SetupLoginStatus() +15
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,
>   Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098

Do you have any idea how I can stop this exception from being thrown? Also CustomErrors are ON for this site and it bypasses the error page, instead it shows the exception. I just want to prevent the users from seeing this ugly exception.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to access the users profile when they are no longer authenticated. I would reccomend that you consider implementing a Login View OR checking for authentication before accessing the users profile properties:

1. **Login View:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.anonymoustemplate(v=vs.100).aspx
2. **Check Authentication:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Worst case scenario we'll resort to Login View (the site was initially implemented without membership so we kept the original controls but unfortunately LoginView was not used). Also as for the Authentication check, I'm doing this outside of pages inside a class so I don't have access to the Request object. I could however try to route it through a master page. Will return with results.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my current way of checking if a user is authenticated is if HttpContext.Current.User != null